# How to record values in a for loop to use for a calculation later

Tags: java, for-loop

For this, i want to write a program where a person enters how many puzzles the animal solved and store the values and add them together

How would i implement something that records the number of puzzles each animal solves and adds them together?

for example:

How many puzzles did animal 1 solve? 5

How many puzzles did animal 2 solve? 2

How many puzzles did animal 3 solve? 1

How many puzzles did animal 4 solve? 3

The animals solved a total of 11 puzzles

```
     for(int puzzleNum = 1; puzzleNum <= 4; puzzleNum++)

     {
         textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many puzzles did animal "  + mazeNum + " solve?");

         mazesSolved = Integer.parseInt(textinput);

   }
```

Comment: Stop trying to get StackOverflow to do your homework.

Comment: Please describe your actual problem. What information are you missing which prevents you from doing that?

Comment: @CharlesForsythe why stop when we keep providing the answers? Questions like these show a complete lack of effort applied to trying to solve it on their own.

Comment: @CharlesForsythe looking at his other questions he seems to be quite successful at it. Seems like he is aiming at a career in lower management :)

Comment: @CharlesForsythe I prefer to just answer them (especially if it only takes 6 seconds). People like this will get caught eventually, especially when their solution is literally on the internet with them asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add it up along the way.

```
int mazesSolved = 0;   
for(int puzzleNum = 1; puzzleNum <= 4; puzzleNum++)
{
    textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many puzzles did animal "  + mazeNum + "solve?");
    mazesSolved += Integer.parseInt(textinput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int mazesSolved = 0;

for(int puzzleNum = 1; puzzleNum <= 4; puzzleNum++)
{
     textinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many puzzles did animal "  + mazeNum + " solve?");
     mazesSolved += Integer.parseInt(textinput);
}
```